# Is there a way for GitHub to "ignore" files when number crunching?

Tags: github

So my friends and I are collaborating on a project, which involves generating and testing out a ton of machine learning models. For convenience sake, we have our own model directory to store our saved models, and we keep our datasets on the repo too.

I've attached a picture of our statistics below.
[image]

As you can see, these stats don't really make much sense because GitHub counts the lines in the binary and dataset files too, so it doesn't really give an accurate estimation of our contributions. Also, gitignoring those models/dataset files isn't an option.

Is there a way for me to tell git to ignore certain filetypes before doing its number crunching? If not, can this be considered scope for further improvement?

Thanks.